# Reading a property against an entity is changing the ID I've overwritten on another property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have this entity:

```
public class SalesOrder : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual CustomerContact DeliveryContact { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomerContact BillingContact { get; set; }
}
```

I then run this code:

```
if (viewModel.DeliveryContact != null && viewModel.DeliveryContact.Id.ToInt() > 0)
    order.DeliveryContact = customerService.GetContactById(viewModel.DeliveryContact.Id.ToInt());

if (order.BillingContact.Id == 0)
    order.BillingContact = order.DeliveryContact; //This doesn't actually get hit.
```

When I start off, both the `order.BillingContact.Id` and `order.DeliveryContact.Id` are `4`. `viewModel.DeliveryContact.Id` is `2`.

When I process the first `if statement`, `order.DeliveryContact.Id` now reads `2` as I expect BUT when the next if statement `order.DeliveryContact.Id` is reset back to `4`. It appears that the first time `order.BillingContact` is read, it overwrites values I've assigned to the `DeliveryContact`. I can reproduce this by using a watch on `order.BillingContact` because when I add the watch, I see the value of `order.DeliveryContact` change as well.

This only seems to happen when both the delivery and billing contact start off with the same Id (in this case 4).

This seems like very odd behaviour. My only guess at this point is that becuause they start with the same ID, entity framework is using the same reference for both properties so when I read the BillingContact for the first time, the value I've assigned is overwritten becuase of lazy loading?

NOTE: if I was to add `var someTempPlaceHolder = order.BillingContact.Id;` above the `DeliveryContact.Id` assignment, it all works as I've loaded the `BillingContact` by that point.

Any ideas?

p.s If I run the code above a second time, the correct ID is assigned so it's definitely the first load causing issues.

Comment: Where is your view model? You need to provide more code.

Comment: Supplying the view model won't help here. I've already stated the ID that has is Ok. I've also clearly shown where the issue happens. It's only when that value is read that the Id I changed is reset.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually found the answer to this whilst debugging a separate issue a while later. Basically, it's down to lazy loading.

When you access the property for the first time, it read the value from the database. **This includes setting the value**

So `order.DeliveryContact = myValue` would actually get the value from the database the first time and then the next assignment would overwrite it.

It worked when debugging because I would hover over the value and read it to check it.